# Page Not Found when improving a suggested edit to a tag wiki body

Tags: bug, tag-wiki, suggested-edits

I reviewed a [suggested edit to a tag wiki](https://unix.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/1975) and decided to click `Improve`. I wrote some text (at https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/39283/edit?improve=true), then submitted my edit. I was brought to the page https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/39283/edit-submit/4bdaca9d-92ce-46bf-a705-c4173a590824 with a content identical to the [404 page](https://unix.stackexchange.com/404).

I think the suggested edit, which created the tag wiki, was approved between the time I clicked `Improve` and the time I clicked `Save Edits`.

Comment: I have since then made my edit from the tag wiki page. The only traces of the bug are in the server logs.

Comment: [Improving suggested edit tag wikis leads to a 404](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/87036) looks similar

Comment: Hmm... Can't reproduce this *just* by approving a tag wiki edit and then submitting an improvement to it in another (previously opened) window - get a warning that it's been edited in the meantime. But yeah, you submitted your improvement 3 seconds after Mrozek approved the edit.